# Data Modeling, Flask-SQLAlchemy and Plugins

Tags: python, plugins, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I working on a website based on Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy with MySQL. I have a handful bunch of feeds, each feed has a few data, but it needs a function.

At first, I used MySQL-python (with raw SQL) to store data, and feeds were on plugins system so each feed overrides update() function to import data by its way.

Now I changed to use Flask-SQLAlchemy and added Feed model to the database as it helps with SQLAlchemy ORM, but I'm stuck at how to handle `update()` function?

1. Keep the plugins system in parallel with the database model, but I think that's unpractical/noneffective.
2. Extend model class, I'm not sure if that's possible, e.g. FeedOne(Feed) will represent item(name="one") only.
3. Make `update()` function handle all feeds, by using `if self.name == ""` statement.

Added some code bits.

Feed model:

```
class Feed(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    datapieces = db.relationship('Datapiece', backref = 'feed', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

`update()` function

```
def update(self):
    data = parsedata(self.data_source)

    for item in data.items:
        new_datapiece = Datapiece(feed=self.id, name=item.name, value=item.value)
        db.session.add(new_datapiece)

    db.session.commit()
```

What I hope to achieve in option 2 is:

```
for feed in Feed.query.all():
    feed.update()
```

And every feed will use its own class `update()`.

Comment: Could you share some bits of code, so we could get a better understanding of your `Feed` model and `update()` method?

Comment: @Audrius I added code bits to the question.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you want. But if you are trying to update an existing record in the database don't recreate it. Query the database and then manipulate the attributes of the resulting object(s) and then `commit()`. The other thing that confuses me is where your `update()` method resides. Is it part of your model?

Comment: @Cfreak I already do that, the code I posted was just a short sample, thanks for the suggestion. Now regarding `update()`, in option 1 which I use right now, `update()` reside in the plugging system, each Feed has its own plugin which overrides `update()`, the problem is I don't like having plugging system and database table at the same time as they're not tightly-connected. I updated the question, add 3rd option and a sample for option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the class and adding an .update() method is just how it is supposed to work for option 2.
I don't see any problem in it (and i'm using that style of coding with flask/sqlalchemy all the time).

And if you (can) omit the dynamic lazy attribute you could also do a thing like:

```
self.datapieces.append(new_datapiece)
```

in your Feed's update function.